# How to pass command line options using python's command line shell?

Tags: python

This is my program(test.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, getopt
def main(argv):
   inputfile = ''
   outputfile = ''
   try:
      opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
   except getopt.GetoptError:
      print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
      sys.exit(2)
   for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == '-h':
         print 'test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("-i", "--ifile"):
         inputfile = arg
      elif opt in ("-o", "--ofile"):
         outputfile = arg
   print 'Input file is "', inputfile
   print 'Output file is "', outputfile

if __name__ == "__main__":
     main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**Using msdos command line I could pass the -h option(defined in test.py) like this:**

```
python test.py -h
```

**The msdos command line would then ouput this:**

```
 test.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>
```

**But how would i pass the -h option in python interactive
mode as was done using the msdos command line?**

Answer (score 1):

May be you could try to hack something with a custom `sys.argv` but this would be way too hacky, use instead:

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> call(['./test.py', option1, option2, ...])
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of the `if __name__ == "__main__":` line is that this file can be used both as a program and as a module.

So do this:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.main(['-h'])
```

If your module wouldn't have the `__name__` check you could do just assigning to `sys.argv`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv = ['-h']
>>> import test
```

But naturally that would only work the first time the module is loaded. For the next runs you will need to run:

```
>>> reload(test)
```

Note: In Python2 `reload` is a built-in, but in Python3 it is in module `imp`.